# Add logo to the page in orchard theme

Tags: c#, css, orchardcms

Currently I am working on creation of a theme for orchard web site, and need to add logo image to the page. My requirements are to show logo image on same level as navigation menu.

```
LOGO         Home | Blog | About Us
```

I can add LOGO image to Header zone and use css to make it shown on same level as Navigation zone, or add LOGO image to the Navigation zone. What will be the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add your logo at the top of your `<header>` zone and use CSS to make the logo inline with your `<nav>` zone. You already have a Home link in your nav menu so repeating the link on your logo (assuming you link the logo to your home page) inside the same navigation menu is not recommended.

```
<header>
<a href="home"><img src="logo"></a>
    <nav>
       <ul>
         ...
       </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```